# jquery fadein and out effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I designed a simple web page here is the html code

```
<div class="wrap-01">
        <div class="wrap-02">
            <div class="about">
                <p> some content </p>
            </div> <!-- end about page -->

            <div class="contact">
                <p> some content </p>
            </div> <!-- end contact page -->

            <div class="service">
                <p> some content </p>
            </div> <!-- end service page -->

            <div class="quotes">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>“ some quote ” - author - </p>
                </blockquote>

                <blockquote>
                    <p>“ some quote ” - author - </p>
                </blockquote>

                <blockquote>
                    <p>“ some quote ” - author - </p>
                </blockquote>

                <blockquote>
                    <p>“ some quote ” - author - </p>
                </blockquote>
            </div> <!-- end quotes page -->
        </div> <!-- end wrap 02 -->

        <div class="wrap-03">
            <a href="#" class="link-01"> About <br /> <span> some text </span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="link-02"> Contact <br /> <span> some text </span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="link-03"> Service <br /> <span> some text </span> </a>
        </div> <!-- end wrap 03 -->
    </div> <!-- end wrap 01 -->
```

I wrote css for this html coding here it is

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{font-family: Arial;}
.wrap-01{
    width: 740px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

.about, .contact, .service, .quotes{
    height: 350px;
    width: 700px;
    background: #fff;
}

.wrap-02{
    position: relative;
}

.wrap-03{
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.about, .contact, .service{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.about p, .contact p, .service p{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.my-link{
    float: left;
    background: orange;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.link-01{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.link-02{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.link-03{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

and here is my jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link-01").click(function(){
            $(".about").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".contact").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".service").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".quotes").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

so now i want to keep about, contact, service, quotes divs by this order when the page loading quotes div should show first and others(about, contact, service) should hide and when I click the link-01 about link should show and others(contact, service, quotes) should hide using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut effect so I want to do this to others(link-02 and link-03).

now I want to know How to I do this thing correctly
is this jQuery code wrong or this isn't correct?
when I click the link-01 all wrap-03 getting hide why this is?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link-01").click(function(){
            $(".wrap-02 div").hide('slow',function(){
                $(".about").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

or if you go with some change in the markup, you can generalize this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".wrap-03 a").click(function(){
    var className = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".wrap-02 div").hide('slow',function(){
            $("."+className).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
<div class="wrap-01">
        <div class="wrap-02">
            <div class="about">
                <p> some content </p>
            </div> <!-- end about page -->

            <div class="contact">
                <p> some content </p>
            </div> <!-- end contact page -->

            <div class="service">
                <p> some content </p>
            </div> <!-- end service page -->

            <div class="quotes">

            </div> <!-- end quotes page -->
        </div> <!-- end wrap 02 -->

        <div class="wrap-03">
            <a href="#" id="about" class="link-01"> About <br /> <span> some text </span> </a>
            <a href="#" id="contact" class="link-02"> Contact <br /> <span> some text </span> </a>
            <a href="#" id="service" class="link-03"> Service <br /> <span> some text </span> </a>
        </div> <!-- end wrap 03 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a jsFiddle with a working example based on your JS and markup. You need to tweak your CSS, I'm not good at that.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/nczUN/1/